# TFS 2012 source control structure with branches

Tags: tfs

I am researching how I'd like to re-structure my companies source control with TFS.  The hurdle that I keep getting hung up on is the proper way to structure the source control.

Consider the following 3 project examples:

- **ProjectA.UI**
- **ProjectA.Common** (domain classes used on both sides.  Currently a part of the same solution as ProjectA.UI and included in the ProjectA.WCF solution.)
- **ProjectA.WCF**

---

**Option 1 (seperate all three into seperate solutions each under their own MAIN branch):**

- TeamProject

  - ProjectA

    - ProjectA.UI

      - MAIN

        - Source

          - .sln is here
    - ProjectA.Common

      - MAIN

        - Source

          - .sln is here
    - ProjectA.WCF

      - MAIN

        - Source

          - .sln is here

**Option 2 (seperate all three into seperate solutions all under a MAIN branch):**

- TeamProject

  - ProjectA

    - MAIN

      - ProjectA.UI

        - Source

          - .sln is here
      - ProjectA.Common

        - Source

          - .sln is here
      - ProjectA.WCF

        - Source

          - .sln is here

**Option 3 (put all three in the same solution under a MAIN branch):**

Can someone point out some flaws in my designs or give me some pointers on a better idea?

Comment: Did you get your inspiration from the [vs branching and merging guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/releases)?

Comment: yes, I have looked over the ALM Rangers guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the UI and WCF projects depend upon the Common project then all three should be in the same solution file. I personally would use option 3.

Benefits are:

- Only one solution to build.
- You can release all three projects from one branch.
- When you branch (for a release or vNext) you get all the projects together.